# Unable to change the file name of core dump file

Tags: c, linux, gdb, coredump

I have done the following changes:

1. Edited the file `/etc/security/limits.conf`, so that the core file size is 'unlimited'. Verified it using the command `#ulimit -c` which shows as 'unlimited'.
2. Appended the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` as per the following:
   `kernel.core_uses_pid = 1`
   `kernel.core_pattern = /tmp/%e.core.%p`
   `fs.suid_dumpable = 2`
   Saved the changes using `sysctl -p`
3. compiled the file as follows:
   `$gcc -g pointer.c -o pointeraccess`
   result-successfully compiled
4. Executed the file in GDB as follows:
   `$gdb pointeraccess`

After getting an arithmetic exception, it outputs as follows:

> (gdb) run
>
> Starting program: /media/anand/d258641a-8cc6-4fcf-96e4-
>
> ce7a147cb34e/Important/Debugging Workspace/pointeraccess
>
> Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
>
> 0x08048477 in main () at pointeraccess.c:13
>
> 13        i=i/0;
>
> (gdb) gcore
>
> Saved corefile core.1880

My question is: Why the filename is `core.pid` instead of `program_name.core.pid` ?

Comment: because it's gdb saving the core file in your case, not the OS. See `help gcore` in gdb.

Comment: @mfro Thanks for the reason & suggestion.  But how do I make the core file name as required ? i.e. **program_name.core.pid**

Comment: did you try my suggestion? It will tell you.

Comment: @mfro Yes, I did. It says as follows:  (gdb) help gcore
Save a core file with the current state of the debugged process.
Argument is optional filename.  Default filename is 'core.<process_id>'. We can't use this because the name in 'binary_name.core.pid' is dynamic based on PID number. So, how do we move forward ?

Comment: why don't you then just do a `gcore this_is_a_corefile_with_the_name_i_want`?

Comment: some of us create scripts and we want the stuff to go to the right file name that includes process name and pid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the core-pattern:

`echo "core.%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`

%e indicates the name of the binary

With the above pattern, I was able to have core dumped which contains executable name and pid.

Edit:

Running it outside of GDB results in filename in core file. Running it with GDB, I suppose gcore takes control.

Comment: I have already tried this but no change. I am posting the output after changing the core_pattern file. (gdb) run
Starting program: /Debugging Workspace/pointeraccess 

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x08048477 in main () at pointeraccess.c:13
13  i=i/0;
(gdb) gcore
Saved corefile core.3262
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

 Inferior 1 [process 3262] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
root@anand-OptiPlex-9010:/Debugging Workspace# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
core.%e.%p

Comment: Try running outside of GDB and try?

Comment: I am on Linux 3.13.0-49-generic / Ubuntu 14.04. Do you know if this may have any effect on the output ?

Comment: I doubt. Did you try running as it is and not with GDB?

Comment: Thanks Prabhu. I tried it outside of GDB and I got the core file name as expected. Any ideas/workaround so that it may also be done inside GDB ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75803/discussion-between-prabhu-and-anand-dhole).